# Get string between Two dots c#

Tags: c#

how can i get string between two dots for example ?

> [Person.Position.Name]

for this case I want to get the string "Position"

I can also have three dots ….

> [Person.Location.City.Name]

I want to take all strings between dots

Comment: Find location of first dot, find location of last dot, use SubString to get middle part.

Comment: You mean [Person.Location.City.Name] should return `Location.City`

Comment: In your last example, do you want `Location.City` or `Location` and `City`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
string s = "Person.Position.Name";
int start = s.IndexOf(".") + 1;
int end = s.LastIndexOf(".");
string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

It will return all the values between the first and the last dot.

If you don't want the result with dot between the strings, you can try this:

```
string s = "Person.Location.Name";
int start = s.IndexOf(".") + 1;
int end = s.LastIndexOf(".");
var result = s.Substring(start, end - start).Split('.');

foreach (var item in result)
{
    //item is  some string between the first and the last dot.
    //in this case "Location"
}
```

Comment: this would be better > `int end = s.IndexOf(".", start);`

Comment: @Yahya I tried here, it will return only the second value. With `LastIndexOf` it will return everything between the first and last dot.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a year old question, but the other answers are not sufficient, like they are even pretending that you want "Location.City" because they don't know how to seperate them.. The solution is simple though, don't use indexof.
say you want to seperate the **Four** (not 3) parts:

```
String input = "Person.Location.City.Name"
        string person = input.Split('.')[0];
        string location = input.Split('.')[1];
        string city = input.Split('.')[2];
        string name = input.Split('.')[3];

Console.WriteLine("Person: " + person + "\nLocation: " + location + "\nCity: " + city + "\nName: " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string str = "[Person.Location.City.Name]";
int dotFirstIndex = str.IndexOf('.');
int dotLastIndex = str.LastIndexOf('.');
string result = str.Substring((dotFirstIndex + 1), (dotLastIndex - dotFirstIndex) - 1); // output Location.City
```